# IE Webdriver Click() clicking the element but nothing happens

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, internet-explorer-11

I want to click on a element it finds the element and clicks on it as well however the elements state(button name changing) which needs to be changed doesn't change. The code works fine for chrome and firefox but does not work for IE. I am using selenium  I have used .click(), javascript exe, send.keys() and actions

HomeOption.Click();

Thread.Sleep(3000);

//This is where it clicks the element

x.click();

Comment: IE browser is slower as compare chrome and firefox. please check after increasing duration -> Thread.Sleep(XXX);

Comment: I tried but it didn't work for me. I also used actions as well

Comment: what exception are you facing ?

Comment: Nothing. The test passes but thing is it does not do what it suppose to do. For example after clicking the x it should close the page and move to another page. But what happens actually is that it clicks it and nothing changes and test pass

Comment: cant tell you what is happening with limited info

Comment: In the IE browser, try to use F12 developer tools to check whether there has some error (JavaScript error or Network Error) when you click the button? Besides, please also set debugger in your application code, make sure you could find the button with no error? If still not working, can you post enough code to reproduce the problem, it might be easier for us to help you solve the problem?